# how to redirect to same page if page is not validated correctly in html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

`enter code here`i have started working with java script  few days back can any one suggest me how to get stayed in same page if page form is not validated correctly.

```
function myfunction(){
var x,y;
x=document.forms["registration1"]["first"].value;

if(x==""){
    alert("give first name");
    document.getElementById("first").focous;
    return false;
}
else{ window.location="NAUKARI1.html";
}

y=document.forms["registration1"]["UserName"].value;   
p=document.forms["registration1"]["pass"].value;
q=document.forms["registration1"]["repass"].value;
if(y==""){
    alert("give user name");
    return false;
}
if(p!=""){
        if(p==q){

            alert("successful");
        }
        else{
            alert("password Mismatch");
            return false;
        }
}
else{
    alert("enter password");
    return false;
}
```

}

MY PROBLEM IS:
when my page is not validated correctly then it is going directly to action page.i want to stay in the same page .

Comment: Show your JavaScript code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. In this case post your javascript too. Note that `myfunction()` needs to return false if error, true if ok: `function myfunction() {  if (somecondition is not met) return false; return true; }`

Comment: This is an even better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350351/295783